# How do coefficients change in a weighted least squares regression?

Tags: regression, heteroscedasticity, weights

We regress $Y$ on categorical data $X_i,\ i=1,\ldots,\ p$. Suppose this is a large dataset and many of the rows of the design matrix are duplicated. We minimize the dataset as follows:

1. We average $Y$ for each unique row of the design matrix,
2. We perform a weighted regression with each row of the design matrix weighted by its number of duplicates.

How do the regression coefficients and their standard errors in this reduced dataset compare to regression on the raw data?